# MacでVagrantとVirtualBoxを使用してCentOS7環境を作成する

Tags: macos, vagrant, virtualbox

初心者エンジニアです。
MacでVagrantとVirtualBoxを使用してCentOS7環境を作成する際、vagrant upをすると
以下のエラーが発生します。
最終的には192.168.33.10へ接続してhttpdサーバーへアクセスするとこをゴールとしています。

```
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

 setup

Stdout from the command:

Stderr from the command:

bash: line 4: setup: command not found
```

vagrant statusを実行するとrunningと表示されるためvagrantは起動している認識です。

```
Current machine states:

default                   running (virtualbox)

The VM is running. To stop this VM, you can run `vagrant halt` to
shut it down forcefully, or you can run `vagrant suspend` to simply
suspend the virtual machine. In either case, to restart it again,
simply run `vagrant up`.
```

現在の状況で192.168.33.10へ接続すると3分ほどのローディング後、
「ページを開けません。ページ"192.168.33.10"を開けません。このページのあるサーバが応答しません。」と表示されます。

※追記
↓vagrantfileの内容

```rb
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://vagrantcloud.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "centos/7"

  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  # NOTE: This will enable public access to the opened port
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine and only allow access
  # via 127.0.0.1 to disable public access
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  #   vb.gui = true
```

↓vagrant ssh-configの結果

```
Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /Users/muraitakahiro/centos7/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

↓ssh -l vagrant -i .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key 192.168.33.10の結果

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.33.10 port 22: Host is down
```

Comment: これとか参考になるのでは？[Vagrant 事始め 03 - 仮想マシンにログインする](https://qiita.com/centipede/items/f6ec6bf5b78440dbd03c)

Comment: @kunif ありがとうございます。Qiita参考にしてみましたが、`ssh -l vagrant -i .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key 192.168.33.10`を実行すると、`ssh: connect to host 192.168.33.10 port 22: Host is down
`と表示されました。

Comment: ちなみに、その前の `vagrant ssh-config` とかで情報は取得出来ていて、それに応じたコマンドになっているのでしょうか？

Comment: @kunif `vagrant ssh-config`の情報は
`Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /Users/muraitakahiro/centos7/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL`
と取得できています。

Comment: その辺の情報も質問記事の方に追記してみてください。回答が付きやすいかも。

Comment: @kunif 色々と追記してみました。アドバイス頂きありがとうございます！

Comment: こちら [カンタン！ Mac で 仮想環境構築（VirtualBox + Vagrant + CentOS 7)](https://qiita.com/ihara_ozisan/items/5a3f77154aabaf9b8838) だと、`vagrant ssh` だけで接続後ログインしているようです。それでダメなら、いったん全部削除して、この記事に沿って作り直してはいかがでしょう。

Comment: 手元でこの Vagrantfile （末尾に `end` を補いました）で `vagrant up` したところ環境を作成でき、ssh 接続もできました。この前後にホスト (macos) で `ifconfig` を実行すると

vboxnet1: （略）
 ether （略）
 inet 192.168.33.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.33.255

という3行が増えていましたが taka さんの環境ではどうでしたか？
また、`ifconfig`の出力の中に、他に同じネットワークのIPアドレスを持つ（`inet 192.168.33.` みたいな行がある）インターフェースはありますか？

Comment: @criticabug ご回答ありがとうございます！`ifconfig`を実行すると「vboxnet0:（略）」　「ether（略）」　「inet 192.168.33.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.33.255」と1行目が「vboxnet1:」でなく「vboxnet0:」でしたが表示されていました。「en0:」の中に「inet 192.168.0.13 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255」というアドレスはありました。